# Java HashTable size() followed by values() safe in thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, hashtable

I have the following executing sequentially in the one thread:

int size = hashTable.size();

foreach.... in ... hasTable.values()

do something

My question will the foreach be executed size times ?  (even if another thread puts/removes an element meanwhile ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, [`HashTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is thread-safe on method level (multiple threads can call any method at any time) but there is no cross-method synchronization. It's possible that between your two instructions other thread adds/removes or even clears the hashtable.

If you need to keep such invariant, make a defensive copy (doesn't have to be thread safe) and do `size()`/loop on that copy:

```
Map<K, V> map = null;
synchronized(hashTable) {
  map = new java.util.HashMap<>(hashTable);
}
map.size();
for(V v: map.values()) {
  //...
}
```

Here for-each is safe and it's guaranteed to run size-times. Also as noted in comments, you can just synchronize on `hashTable`:

```
synchronized(hashTable) {
  int size = hashTable.size();
  for(V v: hashTable.values()) {
    //...
  }
}
```

However this solution means that only one thread at a time can perform the loop (this can become a bottleneck if your loop takes some time to complete). With defensive copy each thread has its own copy and several threads can loop at the same time. On the other hand this solution *is* better if `hashTable` is very big (expensive to copy) but the iteration is very fast.

Comment: There is one subtlety here.  You will need to `synchronize` on `hashTable` while passing it into the `HashMap`.  The `HashMap` will iterate on the Hastable which can still result in a ConcurrentModificationException.  That being said, +1 for defensive copy idea.

Comment: @JohnVint: +1, thanks, you are right! Code is now uglier, but correct. What do you think about using `hashTable.clone()` instead?

Comment: why copy, why not just wrap both operations in a synchronized block?

Comment: @jtahlborn That answer depends on how expensive a single iteration is

Comment: Ok i get it but if u say i need to synchronize over the hashTable to do the copy.  Does that make it thread safe ? If i use synchronize(hashTable) this blocks access to methods of the hasTable in other threads ? So if that is so isn't enought for me to do this  synchronized(hashTable) {
 int size = hashTable.size();


 foreach.... in ... hasTable.values()


 do something

}

Comment: @JohnVint - true, it also depends on how large the map is and whether copying it provides the same guarantees.  still, my point remains.

Comment: @forcewill - yes, you can do that, which is exactly what my earlier comment was point out, no copying needed.  i added that as a separate answer to make it more obvious than a comment.

Comment: @forcewill: indeed, I expanded my answer to address some of your concerns

Answer (score 1):

If another thread will modify the `hashTable` during the execution of the foreach than your code will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 1):

> Java HashTable size() followed by values() safe in thread?

So it's not `values()` method call that is unsafe.  It's that you open an iterator on `values()` which is backed by the `HashTable`.  It is the iterator which throws an exception if modifications are made to the table while it is iterating.

> My question will the foreach be executed size times ? (even if another thread puts/removes an element meanwhile ?

As mentioned, the `HashTable` will throw an exception if it is modified while you are iterating across it.

`HashTable` has all but been deprecated.  If you are looking for a modern, concurrent version of `HashMap` then you should be using [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) which was added in Java 5.  `ConcurrentHashMap` properly handles the case where modifications happen in the background as you iterate across it without extra synchronization or copying:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<...> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<...>();
int size = map.size();
for (... value : map.values()) {
    // may be called more or less than size if other threads add or delete
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not thread safe, but it can be easily made thread safe like so:

```
synchronized(hashTable) {
  int size = hashTable.size();
  foreach.... in ... hasTable.values() {
    // do something
  }
}
```